# VBScript wait function

Tags: vbscript

i'm trying to convert this function to wait notepad.exe to a generic wait function (that can wait for any process). I can't add a variable in the sQuery without breaking the syntax, is there any way to bypass the problem ?

```
Function wait()
Set svc=getobject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
sQuery="select * from win32_process where name='notepad.exe'"
Set cproc=svc.execquery(sQuery)
iniproc=cproc.count
Do While iniproc = 1
    wscript.sleep 5000
    set svc=getobject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
    sQuery="select * from win32_process where name='notepad.exe'"
    set cproc=svc.execquery(sQuery)
    iniproc=cproc.count
Loop    
Set cproc=nothing
Set svc=Nothing
End Function

Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set wscr = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
wscr.Run "notepad.exe"

wait()

MsgBox "done!"
```

I'm going crazy!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WScript.Shell` object's `Run` method, which you're using to start Notepad, has a built-in mechanism to wait for the process to finish. You don't need the WMI-based `wait()` function in your script at all.

```
wscr.Run "notepad.exe", 1, True
```

The `True` value at the end of the line is what indicates that `Run()` should wait for the process to finish.

But to answer your specific question, add a parameter to the `wait` function. I called it `ProcessName`. Then use this variable instead of `notepad.exe`. When you call `wait()`, you specify the name of the process as an argument.

```
Function wait(ProcessName)
Set svc=getobject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
sQuery="select * from win32_process where name='" & ProcessName & "'"
Set cproc=svc.execquery(sQuery)
iniproc=cproc.count
Do While iniproc = 1
    wscript.sleep 5000
    set svc=getobject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
    sQuery="select * from win32_process where name='" & ProcessName & "'"
    set cproc=svc.execquery(sQuery)
    iniproc=cproc.count
Loop    
Set cproc=nothing
Set svc=Nothing
End Function

Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set wscr = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
wscr.Run "notepad.exe"

wait("notepad.exe")

MsgBox "done!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered by *Patrick S.* However, there are two superabundant lines inside the `Do While` loop and two *unnecessary* lines:

```
Function wait(sPName)
Set svc=getobject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
sQuery="select * from win32_process where name='" & sPName & "'"
Set cproc=svc.execquery(sQuery)
iniproc=cproc.count
Do While iniproc > 0
    wscript.sleep 5000
    'superabundant' set svc=getobject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
    'superabundant' sQuery="select * from win32_process where name='notepad.exe'"
    set cproc=svc.execquery(sQuery)
    iniproc=cproc.count
Loop    
'unnecessary' Set cproc=nothing
'unnecessary' Set svc=Nothing
End Function

Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set wscr = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

sProcessName="calc.exe"
wscr.Run sProcessName
wait( sProcessName)
MsgBox "done " & sProcessName

wscr.Run "notepad.exe"
wait( "notepad.exe")
MsgBox "done notepad.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessTrace")
Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    If objReceivedEvent.ProcessName = "svchost.exe" then msgbox objReceivedEvent.ProcessName
'   msgbox objReceivedEvent.ProcessName
Loop
```

There is `Win32_ProcessTrace` (starts and stops), `Win32_ProcessTraceStart`, and `Win32_ProcessTraceStop`. The script stops and waits for events to occur.